# Do monitors cache data of what was recently view on them?

Tags: display, storage

I know that monitors store some data to bring up the config menu and such. I also know that they are not storage devices and need a computer to get data to display. They cannot store all the data they display, since it's lots of data. But do they have a cache of data the monitor recently displayed?

Comment: Not any monitor I have ever used.

Comment: Depends if you consider burn-in as cache

Comment: It's like making a shadow puppet on the wall… switch off the light & Mr Bunny is no more.

Answer (score 1):

No.

And in answer to "the config menu and such"; this is driven by the [firmware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firmware) programmed into the logic device on the PCB.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the opposite :
The image on the monitor needs to be refreshed
continuously at the given frequency which is called the
[Refresh rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refresh_rate).

The monitor itself has no memory what it just displayed a split-second ago.
The most common rate is 60Hz, meaning 60 times per second.